# Compare 2 struct Arrays

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, struct

i was playing with the idea of comparing 2 arrays of data each of which is built from a struct.  The potential idea behind this was to compare an array from local data against an array from network data and if they are the same then use the local data in an attempt to save time especially when some of the data will be images.

basic code i mocked up for testing is below, however i can't seem able to compare the array's because they are from a struct?  is there a way around this?

```
func compareQuery() {

    struct packStructNW {
        var packName : String
        var packDescription : String
        var packTitle : String
        var packImage : PFFile
        var packID: String
    }

    var packArrayNW = [packStructNW]()

    struct packStructLDS {
        var packName : String
        var packDescription : String
        var packTitle : String
        var packImage : PFFile
        var packID: String
    }

    var packArrayLDS = [packStructLDS]()

    if self.connected {
        let packQueryNW = PFQuery(className: "Pack")
            packQueryNW.order(byAscending: "packName")
            packQueryNW.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objectsArray, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error!)
                } else {
                    if let packs = objectsArray {
                        for object in packs {
                            let arrayName = object.object(forKey: "packName") as! String
                            let arrayDescription = object.object(forKey: "packDescription") as! String
                            let arrayTitle = object.object(forKey: "packTitle") as! String
                            let arrayImage = object.object(forKey: "packImage") as! PFFile
                            let arrayID = object.objectId as String!
                            packArrayNW.append(packStructNW(packName: arrayName, packDescription: arrayDescription, packTitle: arrayTitle, packImage: arrayImage, packID: arrayID!))

                        }
                    }
                }
            })

        let packQueryLDS = PFQuery(className: "Pack")
        packQueryLDS.order(byAscending: "packName")
        packQueryLDS.fromLocalDatastore()
        packQueryLDS.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objectsArray, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
            } else {
                if let packs = objectsArray {
                    for object in packs {
                        let arrayName = object.object(forKey: "packName") as! String
                        let arrayDescription = object.object(forKey: "packDescription") as! String
                        let arrayTitle = object.object(forKey: "packTitle") as! String
                        let arrayImage = object.object(forKey: "packImage") as! PFFile
                        let arrayID = object.objectId as String!
                        packArrayLDS.append(packStructLDS(packName: arrayName, packDescription: arrayDescription, packTitle: arrayTitle, packImage: arrayImage, packID: arrayID!))

                    }
                }
            }
        })

        print(packArrayNW)

        print(packArrayLDS)

        if packArrayLDS == packArrayNW {
            print("they are the same")
        } else {
            print("they are different")
        }


    }


}
```

----------------- EDIT --------------------

Thanks for the solution WERUreo.

in the end i had to move the equatable part to an extension of the struct to get it to work.  I'm sure the way you have shown does work, i just couldn't make it happen without errors.

it compare the arrays, only problem i have now is that the array's aren't completely populated by the time that I'm running the compare code as I'm getting the data in the background.  any idea how to wait for the array to be populated before running the code to compare?

inside main class

```
struct myStruct {
    var packName : String
    var packDescription : String
    var packTitle : String
    var packImage : PFFile
    var packID: String
}
```

outside main class

```
extension PackViewController.myStruct: Equatable {}

func ==(lhs: PackViewController.myStruct, rhs: PackViewController.myStruct) -> Bool {
    let areEqual = lhs.packName == rhs.packName &&
                    lhs.packDescription == rhs.packDescription &&
                    lhs.packTitle == rhs.packTitle &&
                    lhs.packImage === rhs.packImage &&
                    lhs.packID == rhs.packID
    return areEqual
}
```

Comment: Is that code even compiling?  If it is, I feel like we are missing a part of the picture.   You're trying to compare two different arrays that are each holding two different types.  That should be failing right off the bat...

Comment: haha no it does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first off, you shouldn't need to define two separate structs.  One struct would work for both network and local.  You also want to make the struct conform to the `Equatable` protocol.  `Equatable` has one required function, which is the `==` operator.  So for your struct, you'd probably do something like:

```
struct packStruct: Equatable {
    var packName : String
    var packDescription : String
    var packTitle : String
    var packImage : PFFile
    var packID: String

    static func ==(lhs: packStruct, rhs: packStruct) -> Bool {
        return lhs.packName == rhs.packName &&
               lhs.packDescription == rhs.packDescription &&
               lhs.packTitle == rhs.packTitle &&
               lhs.packImage == rhs.packImage && // you need to make sure PFFile is also Equatable
               lhs.packID == rhs.packID
    }
}
```

Then you should be able to compare two arrays of `packStruct`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define equality for array of different types. The code below works for me.

```
func ==(lhs: [packStructNW], rhs: [packStructLDS]) -> Bool {
   ...
}

func ==(lhs: [packStructNW], rhs: [packStructNW]) -> Bool {
    ...
}

func ==(lhs: [packStructLDS], rhs: [packStructNW]) -> Bool {
    ...
}

func ==(lhs: [packStructLDS], rhs: [packStructLDS]) -> Bool {
    ...
}

struct packStructNW {}

struct packStructLDS {}

var packArrayNW = [packStructNW]()
var packArrayLDS = [packStructLDS]()

if packArrayNW == packArrayLDS {

} else {

}
```